# Starting Linux NetworkManager caused probable disruption in network connectivity

Tags: networking, linux-networking, networkmanager

i had a situation on my Linux machines on Production networks, where I had used a script to start the `NetworkManager`, because I needed to fetch some `NMCLI` output details, and NMCLI was not running without NetworkManager service being up.

This has caused a disruption on the network which caused some of the tools connected to the Linux endpoints, to have lost the network connection momentarily.

Since this is still under investigation on what exactly happened, this is still an assumption, as there were nothing else at that time that happened other than the `NetworkManager`service been started by my script.

I need to understand, could NetworkManager cause such disruption ? Does starting it cause any writes to some network configuration files by default, which cause the disruption ? What are the configuration files it uses ? Does it make some change to resolv.conf file ?

Has anyone faced such issues before ?

Please enlighten me on this, so that it can help me in Root Cause Analysis.

Comment: Why would you expect that running a tool made to configure the network wouldn't alter the network configuration? The real question is: why would you use nmcli if you don't intend to have NetworkManager running?

Comment: @A B  So just starting the tool would cause to change some network configurations, even if explicitly not done ?

Comment: Can you also let me know what are the files it tends to change by default ?

Comment: help yourself: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager